# New windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, new-window

I have a bit of difficulty with the code below. Basically, I want the code to, when I press the Enter button, to open the window2 but also close window1 simultaneously so that there is only one window and not two of them.

The code is...

```
from tkinter import *  

def window1():

    window = Tk()
    window.title("Welcome")

    f = Frame()
    f.pack()

    label1 = Label(window, text = "Welcome to the random window")
    label1.pack()

    button1 = Button(window, text = "Enter...", command = window2)
    button1.pack()

def window2():

    screen = Tk()
    screen.title("Pop-Up!")

    fr = Frame()
    fr.pack()

    label2 = Label(screen, text = "This is a pop-up screen!")
    label2.pack()

    button2 = Button(screen, text = "Return", command = window1)
    button2.pack()

window1()
```

Comment: So... what exactly is going wrong? You won't get anything at all here, as you do not main-loop the code. It is very difficult to tell exactly what your asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Bad" because you're using two instances of `Tk`. Try instead using `TopLevel`s.

```
import tkinter as tk

def window1():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title("Welcome")

    # etc etc ...

    tk.Button(window,text="Enter...",command=lambda: window2(window)).pack()

def window2(old_window):
    old_window.destroy()
    # window2 stuff

root = tk.Tk()
root.iconify() # to minimize it, since we're just using Toplevels on top of it
window1()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `Tk()` function, you are creating a new instance of the Tcl/tkinter interpreter. Instead use `Toplevel()` which will make a new window in the current interpreter.